# Trouble with Codeigniter Routes involving a query

Tags: codeigniter, routes, uri

I'm having a little trouble with a CodeIgniter route when there is a query (stuff after the ?) in the URI.  I know it is good practice to replace queries with routes in CI, but I'm importing in a premade messageboard that already does everything with queries.  This is my route:

$route['messageboard/:any'] = "messageboard/index";

Any in this case refers to a script name.  So if it's messageboard/admin.php, I have it load a view that loads my premade messageboard's script "admin.php".  It's working just fine if I do messageboard/admin.php.  It does fine if I do messageboard/admin.php?.  If I put a parameter into the query, however, the route won't correctly send the user to the messageboard controller, and instead sends them to a 404.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?  I would be eternally grateful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys, I solved it.  I needed to change three things.  The first was mtvee's suggestion, which lets it read query strings.  The second one you're going to want to change the $config['permitted_uri_chars'] in the config file to include an equals sign, since it starts off disabled and all query strings will be of the for ?a=34 or something like that.  The third is you need to go to $config['uri_protocol'] and change it from AUTO to PATH_INFO.  Once I did those, it worked.

Comment: in CI 2.0 all that needs to be done is change $config['uri_protocol'] from AUTO to PATH_INFO

Answer (score 0):

I believe CI doesn't do GET out of the box. Check out Enabling Query Strings here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the syntax is:

```
$route['messageboard/(:any)'] = "messageboard/index"; //<-- notice brackets
```

and not

```
$route['messageboard/:any'] = "messageboard/index";
```